# How to create Nested field in index using Elasticsearch Java Client 8

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I have an ES index that is created from Java code level when I index a POJO with ElasticsearchClient.

How do I specify that I need certain fields to be type: "nested" in my index?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify your nested attribute with annotation @Field:

```
@Field(type = FieldType.Nested)
```